# Building APK with Gluon Client Plugin - JDK issue

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

The project that I am using to build APK from is HelloFX subproject from [gluon client samples](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples) project.

I've run **mvn client:runagent** then **mvn client:build -P android**. Build process fails with following error statements.

```
[Thu Jun 03 10:00:02 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [hellofx.hellofx:2299]        write:     545.55 ms,  1.09 GB
[Thu Jun 03 10:00:02 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] [hellofx.hellofx:2299]      [total]: 168,663.25 ms,  1.09 GB
[Thu Jun 03 10:00:02 IST 2021][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Image 'hellofx.hellofx' is a fallback image that requires a JDK for execution (use --no-fallback to suppress fallback image generation and to print more detailed information why a fallback image was necessary).
[Thu Jun 03 10:00:02 IST 2021][INFO] Additional information: Objectfile should be called hellofx.hellofx.o but we didn't find that under /home/manikandan/eclipse-workspace/HelloFX/target/client/aarch64-android/gvm
[Thu Jun 03 10:00:02 IST 2021][SEVERE] Compiling failed.
Check the log files under /home/manikandan/eclipse-workspace/HelloFX/target/client/aarch64-android/gvm/log
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/client/ for more information.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  09:55 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-03T10:00:02+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:client-maven-plugin:0.1.41:compile (default-cli) on project hellofx: Compiling failed
```

Full log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/KqDbx2Fg).

Here's the pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hellofx</groupId>
    <artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>HelloFX</name>

    <properties>
        <main.class>hellofx.HelloFX</main.class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>15.0.1</javafx.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.5</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
        <client.maven.plugin.version>0.1.41</client.maven.plugin.version>
        <charm.version>6.0.6</charm.version>
        <glisten.afterburner.version>2.0.5</glisten.afterburner.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.10</attach.version>
        <connect.version>2.0.1</connect.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added jackson dependency here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Added JavaTime data type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${client.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                     <target>${client.target}</target>
                     <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                     <reflectionList>
                        <list>hellofx.Person</list>
                        <list>com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory</list>
                     </reflectionList>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <client.target>host</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>ios</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>android</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

First I through there are some issues with JDK. So I'd reinstalled openjdk 11 once again. But, still this issue occurs.

The JDK that I'm using,

```
manikandan@manikandan-VirtualBox:~/eclipse-workspace/HelloFX$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
manikandan@manikandan-VirtualBox:~/eclipse-workspace/HelloFX$ javac -version
javac 11.0.11
```

Why does this error occur? and how to solve this issue?

Comment: The error is at the beginning of the log: `Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.extractScalarFromObject(...).` It also says how you could fix it, by using `<nativeImageArgs><arg>--allow-incomplete-classpath</arg></nativeImageArgs>`. Before doing that, you should check that when running `client:runagent` you explore all scenarios of your app, to discover all possible reflection cases, and then try to build again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've specified `--allow-incomplete-classpath` in pom.xml and it works. I have another doubt. When `client:runagent` is run, a new folder called `META-INF` is created under 'resources' and the config files are placed inside it. Do we have to keep this directory when we commit the changes to a VCS?

Comment: Great. Not necessary, but you will need to run `runagent` again to do another build (and that requires a display and user intervention), so for CI, for instance, it is convenient to have the files already there.

Comment: Yup. I was also thinking about CI. I think committing those config files to VCS seems a better option for me. Thanks for the clarifications.